# React input losing focus after each user interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a route rendered by my App.js using React-Router-Dom (App.js)

```
<Route path="/inputs">
   <Inputs/>
</Route>
```

Which proceeds to a sub-route that renders my form (Inputs.js)

```
<Route path={`${match.path}/new`}>
  <FormGrid>
    <StyledFormControl variant="outlined">
       <InputLabel>
          Name
       </InputLabel>
       <OutlinedInput 
         value={name}
         onChange={handleChange}
        />
    </StyledFormControl>
  </FormGrid>
 </Route>
```

All of this works fine except for the fact that everytime I type in something, it triggers a rerender and makes the field lose focus. Here is the code that is triggered on the OnChange method of the input field.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const handleChange = event => {
  setName(event.target.value); 
};
```

What can I do so I don't lose focus whenever the user types in something?

Comment: My guess would be that a component is unexpectedly unmounting. Can you try and see with componentWillUnmount (or a useEffect ) whether your input is unmounting ?

Comment: @Axnyff following your advice: useEffect inside this component is triggered everytime I typed something in the input.

Comment: @Brian since my input component is getting rerendered at each new interaction with it, is it correct to just tell it to focus at each new render?

Comment: It seems like a bad fix, you should find out why it is unmounted every single time

Comment: You should try and see all the components which are unmounting whenever you type anything